# Datagridview - prevent duplicates in comboboxcell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a ComboboxCell in first cell of Datagridview. This combobox has Datasource from my DB. When I select Item from It, all other cells in a row gets populated by a record from my DB. Now I want to prevent duplicate row entries, based on Comboboxcell selected item. After that I want to clear that Comboboxcell, and keep code running. I managed to do almost everything, but problem is that after msgbox is displayed, code stops working - so when I select ComboboxCell Item again, nothing happens, even in a new row. Here is my whole code:

```
 Private Sub My_DGV_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles My_DGV.CellValueChanged

        If My_DGV.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Column1" Then

            'Prevent duplicates
            For i As Integer = 0 To My_DGV.RowCount - 2
                For j As Integer = i + 1 To My_DGV.RowCount - 2
                    If My_DGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = My_DGV.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value Then
                        MsgBox("You allready selected this item. Duplicates are not allowed.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Warning")
                        My_DGV.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value = " "
                        Dim cbx As ComboBox = DGV_APO.EditingControl
                        cbx.SelectedIndex = -1
                        Exit Sub
                     End If

                 Next
             Next

            OracleconnOpen()

            Using cmd As New OracleCommand()

                Dim SQL As String = "Select NAMES,SURNAMES,STATE FROM My_Table"
                Dim Concat_SQL As String = " Where "
                SQL = String.Concat(SQL, Concat_SQL, " ID_NUMBER = :id")
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("id", My_DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value))
                cmd.Connection = OracleconnOpen()
                cmd.CommandText = SQL
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt.Load(dr)

                My_DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = dt.Rows(0)("NAMES").ToString()
                My_DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = dt.Rows(0)("SURNAMES").ToString()
                My_DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = dt.Rows(0)("STATE").ToString()

            End Using

            OracleconnClose()

        End If

 End Sub

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'SELECT from my DB
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT ID_NUMBER from My_Table"
        Dim dtb As New DataTable()

        Try

            OracleconnOpen() 'Open my connection

            Using dad As New OracleDataAdapter(SQL, OracleconnOpen)
                dad.Fill(dtb)
            End Using

            Column1.DisplayMember = "ID_NUMBER"
            Column1.DataSource = dtb

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Finally

            OracleconnClose() 'Close my connection
        End Try

 End Sub

 Private Sub My_DGV_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles My_DGV.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

        If My_DGV.IsCurrentCellDirty Then My_DGV.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)

 End Sub

 Private Sub My_DGV_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DGV_APO.DataError

        e.ThrowException = False
 End Sub
```

So, what am I doing wrong ? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have an Exit Sub call within your loop that will always execute so nothing after the exit sub will ever be run when you change this value.  If you want to exit the loop and continue running the code after a duplicate is found, that should be done within the If statement.  This code should stop working after the first row is compared even if it is not a match.

Comment: thanks for response, but that was just a mistake done here while posting. My Exit sub is inside If statement. I edited question again. And code doesn't work this way too.

Comment: The rest of the answer is still correct.  Once you get inside the IF statement it will end the sub, which means any code after the loop will not be run.